# Cypress capture window.console

Tags: logging, cypress

I am having hard times trying to get console output so I can access `text` of the logs and do something with it. ( I don't want to use `should` or any other cypress things, but just manipulate text and save it in json)

so I have something like

```js
onBeforeLoad(win) {
        cy.spy(win.console, 'error', (msg) => {
          console.log('LOG: ' + msg)
        })
      },
```

so while it outputs errors into the terminal, I can't seem to get it in `msg`.
Trying similar trick with `stub` but with no joy.

Comment: Can you share your attempt with .stub()?

Comment: Does it just show blank for `msg`? Have you tried saving the text into an object like: `const logData = {}` then inside the function, include `logData[msg] = msg` or does it immediately appear as blank when `msg` is passed on?